# Getting File not found error when running Batch command to delete empty folders and subfolders

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

For some reason I am getting an "File Not Found" Error when I run this DOS command to delete empty folders and subfolders. It looks correct as far as I can tell. Does anyone have any suggestions?

```
for /f "delims=" %%x in (dir /s /b /ad ^| sort /r') do rd "%%x" 2>NUL
```

Comment: The purpose of the `sort /r` is to provide `for` with the directory-names in reverse-alphabetical order, so the longest names appear first in the list. Consequently, the deepest subdirectories of any subdirectory are encountered first. The `RD~ attempts to delete the directory and will only be successful if the target directory is empty, hence if you have a subdirectory which contains three empty subdirectories, then those three are would be deleted and only then would the parent be processed and deleted if **now** empty.

Comment: Adding the opening quote before the `dir` should cure the problem, but as it did not, you need to look further. Two reasons that a directory may be seen as not-detletable are that it actually contains invisible files (typically `thumbs.db`) which you can locate with `attrib *` in the appropriate subdirectory and a permissions problem where you don't have authority to delete the directory. View permissions with `dir /q`.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a tick (') in front of dir. Try this:

```
for /f "delims=" %%x in ('dir /s /b /ad ^| sort /r') do rd "%%x" 2>NUL
```

This is cleaner

```
for /f "delims=" %%x in ('dir /b /ad') do echo.rd /s /q "%%x"
```

Remove the echo. ONLY if the results appear to be correct.

Comment: Thanks! Thank got rid of my error, but its not removing empty folders. Any thoughts?

Comment: I don't think you need the sort (not that it matters). Also I would put the /S on the RD instead of on the dir (probably faster). See RD /?. See my updated answer. I left out the 2>NUL so you see any errors.

Comment: This is a **VERY, VERY BAD** idea. `rd /s /q` is designed to delete an entire directory subtree **REGARDLESS** of whether it is empty or not.

Comment: @Magoo... you are correct! I assumed that is what the op wanted and that he was only having trouble with the empty folders. As I read it again I think maybe you are right and the op is only trying to delete the empty ones... although the original code made no provision for empty folders either. Sorry :(